# Why does ActiveRecord return a UTC datetime in this case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, activerecord, activerecord-calculations

I have three models:

```
class EventInstance 
  has_many: :conflict_resource_bookings 
  belongs_to :event_template
end 

class ConflictResourceBooking
  belongs_to :event_instance
  # Cached to simplify data loading:
  belongs_to :event_template
end 

class EventTemplate 
  has_many :event_instances
end
```

When I'm querying for datetimes, they usually come back in `Time.zone`:

```
Time.zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
ConflictResourceBooking.joins(:event_instance).order("event_instances.starts_at").first.event_instance.starts_at
# => Sat, 11 Feb 2017 15:00:00 PST -08:00
EventInstance.all.minimum(:starts_at)
# => Sat, 17 Dec 2016 13:00:00 PST -08:00
```

But I was surprised in one case, the datetime from ActiveRecord came in UTC, not `Time.zone`:

```
Time.zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
ConflictResourceBooking.joins(:event_instance).minimum("event_instances.starts_at")
# => 2017-02-11 23:00:00 UTC
ConflictResourceBooking.includes(:event_instance).minimum("event_instances.starts_at")
# => 2017-02-11 23:00:00 UTC

# Or, with EventTemplate:
ConflictResourceBooking.joins(:event_template).minimum("event_templates.starts_at")
# => 2017-01-07 23:00:00 UTC
```

In a *different* case, the combination of `joins(...).minimum` *does* return a localized datetime:

```
EventInstance.joins(:event_template).minimum("event_templates.starts_at")
# => Sat, 17 Dec 2016 13:00:00 PST -08:00
```

I would like to get a datetime in `Time.zone`, but I don't know why some of them came back in UTC. Have I made a mistake?
Is there something else I can look into to explain this difference?

---

#### Setting Time.zone

Our application is multi-tenant with users all around the world. In order to show times in the user's timezone, we assign `Time.zone` at the beginning of each request (in a `ApplicationController.before_action` hook). The assigned timezone is from the `User` record, eg `Time.zone = current_user.time_zone`.

In the examples above, I was in `rails console`, so I assigned `Time.zone` directly.

Comment: do you set config time zone in your `application.rb`?

Comment: Thanks for asking! I've updated the question to include how we handle Time.zone.